# Change variable type to/from (TreeViewEventArgs or TreeViewCancelEventArgs)

Tags: c#, treeview, typeconverter

In my c# project , I want to convert variable type from TreeViewEventArgs to TreeViewCancelEventArgs , or in the contrary .

I wrote a code , but there is an error :
"Error  1   'object' does not contain a definition for 'Node' and no extension method 'Node' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

This is a part of my function code :

```
public void func_make_sql_filters_string(TreeViewEventArgs e1 ,TreeViewCancelEventArgs e2)
{
    object value_event_object ;
    Type type_event;

    if (e1 == null)
    {
        type_event = e2.GetType();
        value_event_object = e2;
    }
    else
        //  if(e2 == null)
    {
        type_event = e1.GetType();
        value_event_object = e1;
    }

    var e = Convert.ChangeType(value_event_object, type_event.GetType());
    if (e.Node.Level == 1)
    {
        array_treeView_checking[e.Node.Index] = e.Node.Parent + " = N'" + e.Node.Text + "'";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just change from type A to type B. You have to do some type of conversion, which in your case doesn't really make sense. After all, you are just after the `Node` property of both, so why don't just get that?

```
public void func_make_sql_filters_string(TreeViewEventArgs e1 , TreeViewCancelEventArgs e2)
{
    TreeNode node = e1?.Node ?? e2?.Node;

    if (node == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Both events are null or don't have a related node.");
    }

    if (node.Level == 1)
    {
        array_treeView_checking[node.Index] = $"{node.Parent} = N'{node.Text}'";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you , great solution and very simple .

Answer (score 0):

[Convert.ChangeType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dtb69x08(v=vs.110).aspx) requires that `value_event_object` An object implements the `IConvertible` interface. In this case neither `TreeViewEventArgs` or `TreeViewCancelEventArgs` implement that interface.

You can create manually one object from other:

```
var TreeViewEventArgs e = new TreeViewEventArgs {
    Node = e2.Node
}
```

But, if you only need get access to Node property (assuming almost one event args is not null):

```
node = e1?.Node ?? e2.Node;
```

Comment: Your original code wouldn't've worked. You checked if `e1` was `null`, and, if it was, you were gonna do `e1.Node` which would've thrown a NRE